# sketchware: i want to make button with a default file

Tags: android, sketchware

resume:

i want make a button with a default file. So, every time someone clicks that button it will open this file.

thk for the help, new here (: .

Comment: Please specify the language `Java` or `Kotlin` . And what type of file it is ? From where you want to open ? Please clear your question

Answer (score 0):

Add file picker component(whatever type of format) add on files picked event in component section. Then use read file path block(for whatever file type your reading) with get at 0 of list string and use file path block for list string  Then on button at file picker component block with component name

Answer (score 0):

Add a button and open the `onClick` event for that button, then add an `add source directly` block and enter this code to the `add source directly` block:

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().build());

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+path),mimeType);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
startActivity(intent);
```

`path` and `mimeType` are `String`s,
Don't forget to change `path` to the filepath of your file
and change `mimeType` to the MIME type of your file,

For example:

replace `path` with `"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/My Audio.mp3"`

replace `mimeType` with `"audio/mpeg"` if you want to open a mp3 audio file.

Here is a list of different file types/extensions/formats and their MIME type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types?retiredLocale=en

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also as i have tried and I only this would work.

Add the file in assets folder in .sketchware/mysc/your app number ex 601/app/src/main/assets/

Import these

```
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.os.Build;


import java.io.File;java.io.File file = new java.io.File(s);

if (!file.exists()){

try{

java.io.InputStream asset = getAssets().open("JWI.pdf");

java.io.FileOutputStream output = new 
java.io.FileOutputStream(file);

final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int size;

while ((size = asset.read(buffer)) != -1) {

output.write(buffer, 0, size);

}

asset.close();

output.close();

} catch (java.io.IOException e){

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

}
```